# Create Image from Graphics

Tags: vb.net

In VB.NET, I need to create an `Image` based on a `Graphics` object I have. However, there is no method such as `Image.fromGraphics()` etc. What should I do then?

Comment: What is your Graphics object created from?

Comment: A `Graphics` object, in and of itself, contains no imagery - its a facility to allow imagery to be drawn on *something else* (i.e. some other object). As such, the question makes very little sense.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so isn't it possible to get a reference to that object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404307.aspx) states. Essentialy create a `Graphics` Object from a `Bitmap`. Then use Graphic methods to do what you need to to the `Image` and then you can use the `Image` how you need to. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever stated your Graphics Object is created to enable drawing on another object, it does not have an Image to copy, the object it was created on does.

From above article:

```
Dim flag As New Bitmap(200, 100)
Dim flagGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(flag)
Dim red As Integer = 0
Dim white As Integer = 11
While white <= 100
    flagGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, red, 200, 10)
    flagGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, white, 200, 10)
    red += 20
    white += 20
End While
pictureBox1.Image = flag
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Graphics.DrawImage method](http://Graphics.DrawImage%20Method) and its overloads.

Here's a snippet from one of the examples that draws an image onto the screen, using a Graphics object from Winform's Paint event:

```
Private Sub DrawImageRect(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    ' Create image.
    Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromFile("SampImag.jpg")

    ' Create rectangle for displaying image.
    Dim destRect As New Rectangle(100, 100, 450, 150)

    ' Draw image to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, destRect)
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question...
He has a `Graphics` object and he wants to "pull out" the `Image` from it.