# Vb creating a graph from an array

Tags: vb.net, graph

I have an array of 1-20 numbers (each number in the array also ranges between 1-20) depending on how many questions there were. Each position in the array represents how many users got a certain question correct, for example: Answers(1) is how many people got question 1 correct (e.g. "5" - 5 users got question 1 correct).

I want to create a bar graph which displays this data. Having each question on the X axis with a bar as high as how many students answered that correctly. On the Y axis will be "Scores" which will be 1 to the highest amounts of correct answers for a question (basically if 10 users answered a range of questions, the highest number of correct answers for one question would be the upper limit of the Y axis - e.g. 8).

I would plot the graph by having the bar height depending on how many students answered the question correctly. The X axis would be from an array of questions numbers (e.g. QuestionNumber(1) = Question 1 etc.).

This is in visual basic application. Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this.

Ultimately the best way is to use the graphics object of a picture-box and use the draw functions to paint the graph any way you like it.

[Create Image from Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450591/create-image-from-graphics)

But an alternative and quick and dirty method you can use if this is a one time thing with a fixed set of data is to simply add 20 labels set to a particular colour and width to a tablelayoutpanel and set the height (or width if you want to go that way) each according to the scaling you need for that bar. Remember to turn off the auto-size property.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll look into doing the picture box method. I don't really want to do the label thing :p

Comment: :) Cool. FYI: I have also used the quick and dirt method to do bar graphs on web pages too using sized coloured images. But the graphics methods is way better in VB. You will find you have to repaint it all the time though when the form resizes etc. It's a little trickier than it first appears. @rwan